# TCP connect() always passes

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a very simple TCP client as follows. The problem is that the `connect()` call always returns 0 even when there is no server on the other side.

```
int TcpSend(struct sockaddr_in* ipv4_client, const void* buffer, size_t size) {

    int sd_client = 0;
    int status = -1;

    // Grab an ipv4 TCP socket.
    sd_client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sd_client == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Make the socket non-blocking so that connect may fail immediately
    status = fcntl(sd_client, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if (status < 0) {
        close(sd_client);
        return -1;
    }

    // Bind and connect
    status = connect(sd_client, (struct sockaddr*)ipv4_client, sizeof(*ipv4_client));
    if (status == -1) {
        close(sd_client);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Status: %d %s\n", status, strerror(errno)); //// ??? : I always get status = 0 here

    // Send a message to the server PORT on machine HOST.
    // Ignore the fact that send might not have sent the complete data
    status = send(sd_client, buffer, size, 0);  //// Consequently I get a SIGPIPE here
    if (status == -1) {
        close(sd_client);
        return -1;
    }

    close(sd_client);

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that `connect()` will pass if just binding succeeds and the connection doesn't happen. However it shouldn't happen when the socket is made `O_NONBLOCK`. The code always passes at `connect()` and I get a `SIGPIPE` error inside `send()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was `ipv4_client->sin_family` was somehow 0.

Doing the following fixes the problem.

```
ipv4_client->sin_family = AF_INET;
```

Comment: That doesn't absolve you from having to do some extra processing or error checking before you start to use the socket if you connect in non-blocking mode. The only practical use of doing that is to lower the default connect timeout. If that isn't your purpose, do the connect in blocking mode and then switch.

Comment: @EJP I completely agree that I need more validation. However I was stumped as to why `connect()` was not returning an error. The question was more on those lines - Sorry if it caused any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

After you connect in non-blocking mode you need to call select() with the socket FD in the writable set, i.e. wait until it becomes writable, then either (1) check for errors on the socket via `getsockopt(),` or (2) call connect() again and check the error. Only after all that is it valid to start calling `send()` or `recv().`